# Expanding $\sin(10x)$ with binomial and pascal triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have to derive the formula for $\sin(10x)$ using complex exponent, Binomial formula and Pascal’s triangle to expand the brackets. Here is my solution:

$$
\sin(10x) = \frac{\exp(i10x) + \exp(-i10x)}{2i} = \frac{(\cos x + i\sin x)^{10} + (\cos x - i\sin x)^{10}}{2i}
$$

Using binomial formula and Pascal’s triangle we can get the following:
$$
(\cos x + i\sin x)^{10} = \cos^{10}x + 10 * \cos^9 x * i\sin x - 45 * \cos^8 x * \sin^2 - 120 * \cos^7 x * i \sin^3 x  + 210 * \cos^6 * \sin^4 x + 252 * \cos^5 x * i \sin^5 x - 210 * \cos^4 x * \sin^6 x - 120 * \cos^3 x * i\sin^7 x + 45 * \cos^3 x * \sin^8 x + 10 * \cos x * i\sin^9 x - \sin^{10} x
$$

So, $ (\cos x - i\sin x)^{10} $  has opposite signs for odd terms.

Do I understand correctly that the answer should be the following?
$$
\frac{\cos^{10} x - 45 * \cos^8 x * \sin^2 x + 210 * \cos^6 x * \sin^4 x - 210 * \cos^4 x * \sin^6 x + 45 * \cos^3 x * \sin^8 x - \sin^{10} x}{i}
$$

Comment: You have an early sign error: $\sin(10x) = \frac{\exp(i10x) - \exp(-i10x)}{2i}$. This will affect the cancellations

Answer (score 0):

Almost.  $\sin(10x)$ where $x$ is real will obviously also be real.  The division by $i$ is inappropriate here for your final result.

Also, you have other typos like in your penultimate term having $\cos^3$ rather than $\cos^2$.

Next, what should have survived were the odd terms, not the even terms.  What you wrote was the expansion for $\cos(10x)$, not for $\sin(10x)$

Finally, it is traditional (*but not strictly necessary*) to rewrite the cosines as sines using $1=\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)$ to get for instance $(210(1-\sin^2(x))^6\sin^4(x)$ as the third term

---

Rephrasing...  if $a,A,b,B$ are all real numbers, then the complex number $a+ib$ is equal to $A+iB$ if and only  if $a=A$ and $b=B$.

We have here $e^{i\cdot 10x} = \cos(10x)+i\sin(10x)$ is equal to $(e^{ix})^{10}$ which expands as you rightly wrote as $(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^{10}=\cos^{10}(x)+10\cos^9(x)\cdot i\sin(x)-45\cdot \cos^8(x)\cdot \sin^2(x)$-\cdots$

By the above, the real parts (*the $a$ and $A$ in our metaphor*) must equal implying $\cos(10x)=\cos^{10}(x)-45\cos^8(x)\sin^2(x)+\dots$ and that the imaginary parts must equal implying $i\sin(10x) = 10\cos^9(x)\cdot i\sin(x)-120\cdot \cos^7(x)\cdot i\sin^3(x)+\dots$ (*or rewritten without the $i$'s by factoring $i$ out of both sides*)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a mistake in the first formula. Everything will cancel properly. Thank you for your reply!